# HTML contents different from Google "View page source"

Tags: java, html, user-agent

I've read on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41739578/reading-web-page-source-code-in-java-differs-from-the-orginal-webpage-source-cod) that this has something to see with the user agent used, but I can't find a way to to get the one used by Google.

I'm trying to fet HTML contents from let's say https://www.kayak.fr/flights/TLS-ATH/2019-10-04/2019-10-07?sort=price_a, when I click on "View page source" using Google Chrome, I'm getting prices etc (what I need) but I can't access those with my java code..

Do I have to find the user-agent of my Google Chrome? I found [this page](https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/software_name/chrome/) but I'm getting the exact same result as before using java..

Any ideas?

Here's my code:

```
try{
    URL url = new URL("https://www.kayak.fr/flights/TLS-ATH/2019-10-04/2019-10-07?sort=price_a");
    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.117 Safari/537.36");
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));
    String line;
    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    bufferedReader.close();
}catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The setRequestProperty is really random in this code because I'm still testing.

Comment: Can you post you Java code?

Comment: Just added my code.

Comment: Your request is being redirected to `/h/bots/captcha`. This site obviously doesn't condone scraping of their content

Comment: How they're detecting the difference between a browser and your code is a mystery though. It seems quite sophisticated. Copying everything from the browser request into a curl command still results in the redirect. I'd love to know how they're doing the detection

Comment: And there is absolutely no way? I remember I've been able to change HTML result some year ago, does the redirection has something to see with java? If I'm using PHP or any other language would I get the same result? Is there no way I can use to emulate a browser and then copy-paste HTML code?

Comment: You could try embedding a headless browser, see e.g. https://www.puzzle.ch/de/blog/articles/2018/02/12/phantomjs-is-dead-long-live-headless-browsers.

Comment: I'll give it a try thanks